# "Luckily we didn't get too wet because [we wore raincoats/ we were wearing raincoats]."

Tags: grammar, phrases

Grammatical explanation needed

Which aspect is  correct in this construction?

Comment: They're both acceptable.  Can you explain why you think one might be more correct than the other?  For example, show us the prior research you've done, etc.

Comment: We have learnt that when we use the past continuous and in general continuous tenses we put an emphasis on the duration of the action. Is there any duration here?

Comment: There is no context by which to make the decision in your question. Hence, both are acceptable.

Comment: Have a look at https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290364/simple-present-or-present-continuous/529972#529972

Comment: All right!  Thank you guys :)

Comment: There is a very subtle difference between them. "Wore" suggests a deliberate choice to put the raincoats on because it was raining when they went out; but "were wearing" suggests that they happened to be weraing raincoats when they got wet. If they were wet by a burst hosepipe then "Were wearing" is probably more appropriate, if they were wet by rain that was falling when they left "Wore raincoats" is probably better..

Comment: Very helpful!! Although as a foreign learner I have to admit that this answer was kinda tricky :p

Comment: BoldBen, my view is that if that were true, you'd need to present a lot of justification…

What makes you think "Wore" suggests anything other than "were wearing" does?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Past Simple VS Past Continues](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/336543/past-simple-vs-past-continues)